# Cambiar de pill o tab (pestaña) en bootstrap usando JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Buenas.
 Estoy intentado poner pestañas con bootstrap a mi página web. El problema es que no sé como hacer para que el foco se ponga en la pestaña en la que se ha hecho click. Por foco me refiero a que se vea cual es la que está seleccionada (la pestaña de color rojo en esto caso). He estado buscando en internet y no he encontrado nada que me haya sido útil. 
Adjunto foto de la web con las pestañas y código:

El foco en la foto estaría en Albums.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CÓDIGO:**

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
     if ( $(window).scrollTop() > altura ){
      $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed');
     } else {
      $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
     }
    });
    $("#news").mouseover(function(){
     $("#news").css("background-color", "#800000");
     $("#a").css("color",black);
    });
    
    $("#conciertos").mouseover(function(){
     $("#conciertos").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });   
    
    $("#videos").mouseover(function(){
     $("#videos").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });
    
    $("#songs").mouseover(function(){
     $("#songs").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });    

    $("#lyrics").mouseover(function(){
     $("#lyrics").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });
    
    $("#store").mouseover(function(){
     $("#store").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });
    
    $(".listaArriba").mouseleave(function(){
     $(".listaArriba").css("background-color","#B22222");
    });
    
    $("#albumPill").click(function(){
     $("#albums").show();
     $("#singles").hide();
    });
    
    $("#singlePill").click(function(){
     $("#singles").show();
     $("#albums").hide();
    });
    $("#singles").hide();
    
   });
```

```html
  <header class="headerEnd">
  <div class = "cabecera">
   <ul id = "lista1">
    <a href="home.html" id="fotoEndi"><img src="endikasangroniz.png" id=titulua></a>
    <a href="../EndiIngles/endi.html" id = "o"><img src="../Bandera/uk.png"></a>
    <a href="../EndiCastellano/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/banderaEspana.png"></a>
    <a href="../EndiEuskera/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/ikurrina.png"></     
       </ul>
      </div>
 </header>
 <header class = "header">
  <div class="menu" id="menu">
   <nav class="top-menu">
    <ul class = "navigation">
     <li class="listaArriba" id="news"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos"><a href="gigs.html">GIGS</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="videos"><a href="videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="songs"><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="lyrics"><a href="lyrics.html">LYRICS</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="store"><a href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank">STORE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
     </header>     
      <div class="lyrics">
       <!-- Centered Pills -->
       <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
         <li class="active" id="albumPill"><a href="#">Albums</a></li>
         <li id="singlePill""><a href="#">Singles</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="albums">
    <h3>Aquí saldrían los albumes</h3>
   </div>   
   <div id="singles">
    <h3>Aquí saldrían los singles</h3>
   </div>
  </div>
     <div id="footer">
    <ul class = "navigationFoot">
     <a id="n" href="https://es-es.facebook.com/EndikaSangroniz/" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoFacebook.png" ></a>
     <a id="n" href="https://www.instagram.com/endikasangroniz/?hl=es" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoInsta.png"></a>
     <a id="n" href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank"><img id="soundcloud" src="../IconosRedes/bandcamp.png"></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**PD:** He omitido el código CSS porque no es relevante aquí.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes más que establecer la clase `active` en la pestaña que quieres que se vea como activa:

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    var altura = $('.menu').offset().top;
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
      if ( $(window).scrollTop() > altura ){
        $('.menu').addClass('menu-fixed');
      } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('menu-fixed');
      }
    });
    $("#news").mouseover(function(){
      $("#news").css("background-color", "#800000");
      $("#a").css("color", 'black');
    });

    $("#conciertos").mouseover(function(){
      $("#conciertos").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });   

    $("#videos").mouseover(function(){
      $("#videos").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });

    $("#songs").mouseover(function(){
      $("#songs").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });    

    $("#lyrics").mouseover(function(){
      $("#lyrics").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });

    $("#store").mouseover(function(){
      $("#store").css("background-color", "#800000");
    });

    $(".listaArriba").mouseleave(function(){
      $(".listaArriba").css("background-color","#B22222");
    });

    $("#albumPill").click(function(){
      $("#albums").show();
      $("#singles").hide();
      $(".nav.nav-pills li").removeClass("active");
      $("#albumPill").addClass("active");
    });

    $("#singlePill").click(function(){
      $("#singles").show();
      $("#albums").hide();
      $(".nav.nav-pills li").removeClass("active");
      $("#singlePill").addClass("active");
    });
    $("#singles").hide();

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<header class="headerEnd">
  <div class = "cabecera">
   <ul id = "lista1">
    <a href="home.html" id="fotoEndi"><img src="endikasangroniz.png" id=titulua></a>
    <a href="../EndiIngles/endi.html" id = "o"><img src="../Bandera/uk.png"></a>
    <a href="../EndiCastellano/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/banderaEspana.png"></a>
    <a href="../EndiEuskera/endi.html"><img src="../Bandera/ikurrina.png"></a>     
      </ul>
    </div>
 </header>
 <header class = "header">
  <div class="menu" id="menu">
   <nav class="top-menu">
    <ul class = "navigation">
     <li class="listaArriba" id="news"><a href="news.html">NEWS</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="conciertos"><a href="gigs.html">GIGS</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="videos"><a href="videos.html">VIDEOS</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="songs"><a href="music.html">MUSIC</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="lyrics"><a href="lyrics.html">LYRICS</a></li>
     <li class="listaArriba" id="store"><a href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank">STORE</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
     </header>     
      <div class="lyrics">
       <!-- Centered Pills -->
       <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
         <li id="albumPill" class="active"><a href="#">Albums</a></li>
         <li id="singlePill"><a href="#">Singles</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div id="albums">
    <h3>Aquí saldrían los albumes</h3>
   </div>   
   <div id="singles">
    <h3>Aquí saldrían los singles</h3>
   </div>
  </div>
     <div id="footer">
    <ul class = "navigationFoot">
     <a id="n" href="https://es-es.facebook.com/EndikaSangroniz/" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoFacebook.png" ></a>
     <a id="n" href="https://www.instagram.com/endikasangroniz/?hl=es" target="_blank"><img src="../IconosRedes/iconoInsta.png"></a>
     <a id="n" href="https://endikasangroniz.bandcamp.com/" target="_blank"><img id="soundcloud" src="../IconosRedes/bandcamp.png"></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Ha funcionado! Gracias Asier.